# react navbar component css does not update when id is changed

Tags: css, reactjs

I am trying to put together a responsive navbar but I am having trouble getting my code to respond and I am too new to both to know if the issue is related to react or css.

I am trying to make the menu to hide when the screen is small enough and reappear as a column when the hamburger icon is clicked.  I can see in Chrome that the id is changing, but I am not seeing the css updating accordingly.  Can you help me understand what I am doing wrong?  I am using webpack and css-loader.  I could try inline styling but that is supposed to be bad practice.

**React:**

```
import React, { useState} from "react";
import { Icon } from "semantic-ui-react";
import "../css/App.css";


export default function Navbar (props) {

    const [showLinks, setShowLinks] = useState(false)

    return(
        <nav class='navbar'>
            
            <Icon name='picture' size='large' className='brand' />

            <a href='#' className='toggle-button' id={showLinks ? "active" : "hidden"} onClick={() => setShowLinks(!showLinks)}>
                <span class='bar'></span>
                <span class='bar'></span>
                <span class='bar'></span>
            </a>

            <ul class='navbar-links'>
                <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="/store">Store</a></li>
                <li><a href="/cart">Cart</a></li>
                <li><a href="/checkout">Checkout</a></li>
            </ul>

        </nav>
    )
}
```

**App.css**

```
.navbar {
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    justify-content: space-around;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
}

.brand {
    padding: 1rem;
}

.navbar-links {
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}

.navbar-links li a {
    display:flex;
    color: white;
    padding: 1rem;
}

.navbar-links li:hover {
    background-color: #555;
}

.toggle-button {
    position: absolute;
    top: .75rem;
    right: 1rem;
    display: none;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 30px;
    height: 21px;
}

.toggle-button .bar {
    height: 3px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    .navbar {
        height: 100%;
        align-items: flex-start;
    }

    .toggle-button {
        display: flex;
    }

    .navbar-links {
        display: none;
        width: 100%;
        flex-direction: column;
    }

    .navbar-links ul {
        width: 100%;
        
    }

    .navbar-links ul li {
        text-align: center;
    }

    .navbar-links ul li a{
        padding: .5rem 1rem;
    }
    
    .navbar-links #active {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;

    }
}
```

Comment: "I am trying to make the menu to hide when the screen is small enough" - this is handeled by media queries in CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a related example in media query, you have:

```
.navbar-links {
  display: none;
...
```

Isn't it wrong?

And you shouldn't dynamically change element ID, you should use CSS class for this.
And I think, you confused `class` with `className`, use only `className`

upd:
move `id={showLinks ? "active" : "hidden"}` from `toggle-button` to `ul` like this:

```
<ul id={showLinks ? "active" : "hidden"} class='navbar-links'>
                <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
...
```

then, add to your css

```css
#hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

remove `display: none` from here:

```css
  .navbar-links {
      width: 100%;
      flex-direction: column;
  }
```

example: https://codesandbox.io/s/falling-wind-oeo4o

Comment: When the screen is small I want the menu to disappear so I think display: none; is correct because it should hide the <ul>

Comment: I did try using changing the className but I had the same problem

Comment: I think, I was correct - Check comment update

Comment: That was a silly mistake, thanks so much!!